# How do I make my soldiers better?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've noticed that many of my soldiers in my combat unit have yellow bars on their stats.  I'm assuming that this means they have gained boosts to their attributes.  Is there a limit to the boosts they can receive?

I also noticed that several units also have medals on their portraits are those yellow bars tied to that medal?  Can my soldiers receive multiple medals?

Comment: In Peace Walker there was a limit to how much a soldier could improve, but I wonder how TPP handles it. +1 for the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soldier's stats get a boost based on their Morale. The Morale bar is the blue one next to the Diamond Dogs logo, above the health indicator:

[image: staff management]

Morale ranges from 0-15 and is reset every 36 minutes. Morale is tied strongly to your GMP balance, keep it positive to never lose Morale, Morale also steadily rises as you progress through the game, so long as GMP is positive. You can also raise Morale of soldiers by visiting them at Mother Base, just run up to a soldier so that he sees you and he will salute you, any method that you use to get their attention works, so long as they see you, only the soldier that saw you and saluted to you will get their morale raised, check which soldier it is by marking them (their name will appear above their head).

Source - [this guide](http://mmgn.com/ps4/articles--the-phantom-pain-mother-base-upgrade-guide)

Comment: That's a good guide. You can also improve your soldiers by them getting medals. All three gives a boost.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt yes that is very true, this answer is a few months old now I'm not sure if I can edit it again, BUT the medals part has been confirmed as true, as you can see in that picture above, Komodo Dragon has a cross medal (cant remember what it's for) but THAT medal is what causes the yellow extra ability to show up, from what I remember, you have to play as the character on a few missions, and also send them on deployment and hope they don't die!

Comment: You can always edit your own post. You get 30 AP for each medal. There's no bonus for getting or three, and no difference in the bonus you get for each one.