# How far can a combat ops soldier improve?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Ever since the option came available when I unlocked the Combat Platforms I've been running around as a custom soldier by the name of Amber Fox.

Recently I managed to win my first S-ranked mission complete, and I immediately got a message that her proficiencies had "increased significantly" as well as a distinguished service medal.

When I looked at her profile again, all her skills had indeed upgraded from mostly C-ranks to straight As.

Now my question is: **Is there an upper limit to how far a soldier can be improved in this way?** IE, if I keep at it long enough, would she promote to A+ or even S ranks, or will I hit a ceiling and would be better off taking another soldier on missions to rank that one up as well?

(Note: This is *somewhat* related to the question "[How do I make soldiers better?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/234242/how-do-i-make-my-soldiers-better)", but the only non-deleted answer it has does not answer my question at all -- and in fact it barely answers the question *asked*, but that's another matter).

Comment: I've been using Amber Fox for several missions, and her ranks haven't gone past A. I've seen some statements that there's a limit to how much recruits' skills can improve, but I'm not sure whether that applies to the character you're using, or just the characters in the combat unit who go out on deployments.

Comment: I believe they will improve a set amount when getting a medal, and I think there's 2 or 3 different medals. So after you get these medals that's the highest they'll go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A soldier can receive three medals which will increase their stats.

- The first is for being on a team that completes a number of dispatch missions.
- The second is for successfully completing several missions when
  deployed as a combat unit player character - Which can be getting an S
  rank 3 times, or a lower rank 5 times.
- The third is given when that soldier deals the killing blow/fultons
  out an invader from an FOB attack.

Once a character has all three of these medals, their stats will increase no more. It all depends on their base rank as to how far it'll increase their skills, like a C rank can make it to an A rank, A ranks can become A+, and S+ can max out at S++.